# Login Check with Active Directory + SSL

Tags: authentication, model-view-controller, .net-core, active-directory

I am working on a requirement where I need to validate user with active directory account. 
For this I have used **LdapConnection** with **NetworkCredential** and  **PrincipalContext** and in all cases I am able to validate user **without SSL**.
But I need to use validate user with SSL. I have also used the correct port i.e **636/TCP   LDAP SSL**

Following is the code I did with **PrincipalContext**

```
using (principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ldapServerIp, null, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer, userName, password))
                { bool isCredentialValid = principalContext.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);}
```

Following is code I did with

```
using (ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(ldapServerIp))
                {
                    var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(_username, _password, ldapServerIp);
                    ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
                    ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
                    ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);

                }
```

Does anyone have did this earlier successfully. If there is any solution that will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those should work just fine, as long as you specify the LDAPS port (usually 636). So your `ldapServerIp` variable should be set to something like `example.com:636`.

Comment: yes i did that 636 is for SSL connectivity. But did not work.

Comment: It's possible the certificate is not trusted on the computer you're doing this on. You can use the PowerShell in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22251597/1202807) answer to download the certificate. Use `https://example.com:636` as the URL, and it will save the certificate to a .cer file. Open that file, and it should tell you if the certificate is trusted or not.

Comment: Is there something that I need to check what type of encryption used in signing certificate e.g #SHA, #MD through code.

Comment: No. It's exactly the same type of certificate that is used for websites.