# Decoding Base64 files in windows

Tags: windows, command-line-tool, certutil

So I have been tasked with automating getting certs for 1000 devices. And have been working though converting a Linux script to windows to match up with other scripts we have for other sections for this automation. To that end I have been able to download the cert with the command below into what I believe is a base64 (if I am reading the Linux script correctly) file but all attempts to decode it have failed.

```
curl --connect-timeout 30 --max-time 60 -sk <redacted) -X POST -d @cert-retrieve-testtop10.gc.com.json -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <redacted>" > NAME.b64
```

The Linux script is using the below command to do this

```
# extract the combined cert from it base64 file
jq .CertificateData $CERT_NAME.b64 | sed -es/\"//g | base64 --decode > $CERT_NAME.out
```

I have tried using the windows command

```
certutil -decode output.txt decoded.txt
```

but got the following error

DecodeFile returned The data is invalid. 0x8007000d (WIN32: 13 ERROR_INVALID_DATA)
CertUtil: -decode command FAILED: 0x8007000d (WIN32: 13 ERROR_INVALID_DATA)
CertUtil: The data is invalid.

Comment: Have you looked at the .b64 file to confirm that it is absolutely 100% a base64 file and not like an error message or something?

Comment: Can these [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233702/) help you to download certificates by powershell?

Comment: @SomethingDark here is what is in the file sorry unsure how to just attach the file. 

It starts with {"CertificateData":" 

it ends with =","Filename":"labtesttop.wsgc.com.pem","Format":"Base64"}


I see nothing that says error or hints at it. Also the same file is decode-able with the Linux jq command above

Comment: @Daemon-5 I would love to do that in PS or BAT. Here is the issue we are having we switched certs getting requested form a CA to a cert issuing program. Which is fine for 1 or 2 devices but we have over 1000 in my department alone. To top that off the devices we have are very limited small kernel OSs not typical server/desktops. So the certs not only have to be in particular formats (CER and KEY) but uploaded in a certian order and other commands issued between uploads as well.

We had everything working in batch scripting, but then they changed the CA policies.

Comment: @Daemon-5 Currently we have figured out from using a Linux script (snip-it above) how to request and DL the certs but they are DL'ed into a bas64 format that I can not figure out how to decode to the CRT and KEY files.

Comment: Based on the fact that the data ends with a `=`, it indeed sounds like there's base64 data in the file, but unfortunately, `certutil` expects the entire contents of the file to be the base64 data and nothing else. I can imagine a fairly ugly hack to extract the pure data and then decode that involving using powershell to parse the JSON, though.

Comment: @SomethingDark Yea I have found that what certutil needs is everything in between the {"CertificateData":" and  ","Filename":"labtesttop.wsgc.com.pem","Format":"Base64"} The = is the last character in the encoded file I need. If I can remove the rest then I can use certutil to decode the file